# Does aws s3 Transferutility.upload() returns a response?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading large files (> 2gb) to aws s3 bucket from a desktop application. The functionality is working fine. In aws documentation it says that multipart uploads returns an uploadid when it is called. Since it has no return type, I am not getting anything. I need that upload id. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See following for examples : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-upload-part.html

Comment: Is the uploadID only available for s3 glacier?